# Enable multi tenant in skype for business

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, skype-for-business

I have some issues need support.
I using Skype For Business for Web SDK, if using my account or any account in organization, it's OK. But when i using another organization, it not run.
I had enable multi tenant in Application in Azure Active Directory but it still not run.
maybe, i need permissions some function. But i don't known or don't understand it.
How to setting it?

Comment: Please try to allow domain to log on. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Allow-users-to-contact-external-Skype-for-Business-users-b414873a-0059-4cd5-aea1-e5d0857dbc94

Comment: Please post your fix so that it may help anyone else when they come here with a similar problem